# DataGrid problems. Using DataSet.Merge with "Edit Template"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I am trying to debug an issue with a WinForm application.

The application uses a DataGridView bound to a DataSet.

The user can select a row and click "Edit" and an Edit Form appears so the user can edit the row and save his changes.

If the DataGridView is sorted by one or more columns and the user edits a row more than once and changes that rows position in the DataGrid (by changing one of the sorted columns TWICE), the DataGridView gets out of sync and I get Exception errors.

Here is how the code is written:

When the user clicks a row and hits edit (the user may only select one row), that row is passed to the EditFom. The edit Form creates an empty DataSet and loads that Row. When the user is done, the calling form uses DataSet.Merge to merge those changes back into its DataSet.

Here are a couple of scenarios that tell me it is womething to do with the "merge" and sorting:

(Note, I never change the actual "sorting", I am talking about changing the value of one of the sorted by columns in one of the rows.)

1. If the user edits a row directly in the Grid and changes the value of one of the columns being used to sort, then changes it again, etc. The row moves around the Grid, like it should and when the user clicks save, everything saves fine.
2. If the user edits a row (directly in the Grid OR via the "template") and doesnt change any of the "sort" columns, just makes an edit (therby setting the "State" of the row to Modified, right...), THEN the user edits the row using the Template (which goes through the seperate DataSet and merges the data back when done), and changes one of the columns being sorted (when done, the grid should resort and the row should "move"), the row doesn't get REPAINTED, it stays in the same position in the grid that it was in before the template edit. (Although, the data saves fine and you can refresh the grid and it sorts properly.) Evidently, the DataGrid isn't being notified that the RowChanged in this scenario (or it is, but it isn't doing anything about it).
3. If the user edits a row directly in the Grid, change a sort column (the row moves), then edits the row using the template and changes that column again, we get the same results as 2, above. The data saves fine, but when the user leaves the edit template, the grid doesn't resort.

(This is the one that causes the Exception error.)

1. If the user edits a row using the template and changes a sort column and leaves the template, the datagrid resorts and the row moves properly. Then, if the user edits the SAME row using the Template Edit and changes the sort column AGAIN. When the user leaves the edit template, the datagrid doesn't resort and when the user saves the data and the grid refreshes, we get an error:

System.InvalidOperationException: DataTable internal index is corrupted: '5'.

And sometimes, we get an error complaining the primary key is missing.

Any advice on how to "debug" this? I feel like it has something to do with the "internediate" dataset the edit template uses and the "Merge". It is like the DataGrid datasource is getting out of sync with the DataGrid Rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have done some Google'ing before posting this. It seems to be a common error and I found a HUGE post about this on the MS site. Unfortunately, I haev tried most of their suggestions, but most likely I will find my answer there. I just wanted to make a note of this, in case anyone is interested:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/18544cd3-1083-45fe-b9e7-bb34482b68dd

Comment: I suppose I am just going to have to prevent the user from editing a row more than once (without saving). That seems to be the only solution. There are many posts and articles about these problems on the web and it seems to be an ongoing issue.